# updating data in database on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to update data in database using after_create callback
I wrote

```
Dm::Advertisement.where (:type => Dm::Advertisement).update_all(ads_counter: 0)
```

in my model , but have SyntaxError. Can anyone point me where i did mistake?

Comment: How about telling us what error you get? And maybe the part of the code that generates the error? (Just copy the message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dm::Advertisement.where (:type => Dm::Advertisement).update_all("ads_counter =0")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dm::Advertisement.where (:type => Dm::Advertisement).update_all(:ads_counter => 0 )
```